# Php, Mailing Every Month

Tags: php, email

I want to report sth every new month via email. How can i do that? 
Assume that no body enters the site in all month.

Sory about my english and i'm new about php.

Thanks
B.

Comment: bhdrkn, there's a lot of info around about this, search a bit on Google and then ask if you have some concrete doubts.

Comment: What OS is your site running on? Ok Windows apparently (you should add this info as an edit to your original post or as a comment, not as an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you have to use a Scheduled Task to do this.

See [How to schedule a task in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/85297/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-windows-7) for more info.

If it's just a basic php script you want to run, then I would create a simple .cmd file, containing the following :

```
@echo off
C:\php\php.exe D:\path\to\your\script.php
```

Save this and add it as a scheduled task (changing paths and filename of the script as you see fit of course).

Answer (score 4):

Using a [cron job](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/) would be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but at least I know cron job work only for linux systems but i use Windows 7

Comment: Windows has Task Scheduler which does the same thing.

Comment: Also, you should use "add comment" on Luke's answer not make a new answer. That way everything will be kept together.